# Не работает автозапуск службы systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, systemd, systemctl

После перезагрузки сервера статус службы:

```
systemctl status weblog.service
● weblog.service - weblog
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/weblog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Хотя автозагрузка включена, при этом если написать `systemctl strt weblog.service` служба поднимается.

```
systemctl -l status weblog.service
● weblog.service - weblog
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/weblog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-05-24 12:07:34 MSK; 1min 38s ago
   Main PID: 1359 (start_weblog.sh)
      Tasks: 9 (limit: 9504)
     Memory: 107.6M
        CPU: 1.862s
     CGroup: /system.slice/weblog.service
             ├─1359 /bin/sh /root/Web-store/start_weblog.sh
             └─1360 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Файл службы: cat /lib/systemd/system/weblog.service

```
    [Unit]
      Description=weblog
    
    [Service]
      ExecStart=/root/Web-store/start_weblog.sh
      Type=idle
      KillMode=process
      SyslogIdentifier=weblog
      SyslogFacility=daemon
    
      Restart=on-failure

[Install]
  WantedBy=multiuser.target
```

Подскажите, с чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Comment: "Хотя автозагрузка включена" - где и как вы её включали?

Comment: systemctl enable weblog.service
в этой строке показывает, что она enabled: Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/weblog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Comment: `Restart=on-failure` - а вдруг ваш скрипт запускается, но по какой-то причине сразу завершает свою работу? Почитайте логи `journalctl -b -u weblog` - там точно нету строк похожих на автозапуск?

Comment: `Type=idle` меня тоже смущает, но я точно не помню как он работает, но для чистоты эксперимента можно попробовать не выпендриваться и поставить `Type=simple`

Comment: Изменил `Type=idle`
И вот после перезагрузки:
```
  journalctl -b -u weblog
-- Journal begins at Wed 2022-10-05 17:03:08 MSK, ends at Wed 2023-05-24 13:01:28 MSK. --
-- No entries --
```

Comment: `multiuser` - так стоп, опечатка же, правильно `multi-user`. Сделайте disable, потом исправьте опечатку, потом daemon-reload и потом enable

Comment: Cпасибо, все заработало!